# MAC OS X - Best Screen Saver for Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, screensaver

I'm looking for some nicer screen saver to replace Flurry, I think Mac can do better then that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has a lot of screen savers [online](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/icons_screensavers/). I would suggest flipping through their selection and finding something you like.